# Installing Dionysus OS X 10.11

Tags: boost-python

I tried to install Dionysus on OS X 10.11, having previously installed boost, boost-python using homebrew. Everything works until the very end of the make process, when there's a linking failure:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "boost::python::detail::init_module(PyModuleDef&, void (*)())", referenced from:
          _PyInit__dionysus in dionysus.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[2]: *** [bindings/python/lib_dionysus.dylib] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [bindings/python/CMakeFiles/_dionysus.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried various different ways of installing boost, they all resulted in this error. Does anyone know how to overcome this?